# how to add value on the next blank row in excel using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to create a code that will get the last blank row in an excel file and insert a value like this screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    explicitWait("//div[contains(text(),'$ ')]");
    stopwatch.stop();
    long millis = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    FileInputStream fsIP= new FileInputStream(new File(savepath));
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


    int i = 1;
    while (next()){

             HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
             row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("time: "+stopwatch);
             i++;
         }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe what's wrong in this code.

Comment: I modified the code ang tried to add a null cell object so I can use .next
  
                Cell cell = null;
  int i = 1;
  while (cell.next()){
           
           HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
           row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("time: "+stopwatch);
           i++;
       }

but it doesnt work